# Build errors with Visual Studio S2013 Apache Tools for Cordova project

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2012, mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

I have never touched Cordova nor Ionic before, but yesterday I set things up to build a simple Android app as documented in [this article.](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/paulballard/build-your-first-hybrid-mobile-app-with-visual-studio-2013-angularjs-ionic-and-adobe-phonegap) The article uses the project [Ionic SideMenu Starter Template for Cordova](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Ionic-SideMenu-Starter-8e905eb5). It's a small and simple project that includes and demonstrates the roles and components in a Cordova mobile app, and comprises nearly only HTML 5, CSS, and JavaScript, with the Ionic library over all of those.

When I first build the project, according to the tutorial article, I expect the app to start up in an Android emulator. Instead I get two very unfamiliar build errors:

```
Error   2   C:\Development\Cordova\Golf\Code\IonicSideMenuStarter\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 2    C:\Development\Cordova\Golf\Code\IonicSideMenuStarter\ERROR building one of the platforms   1   1   IonicSideMenuStarter

Error   3   C:\Development\Cordova\Golf\Code\IonicSideMenuStarter\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 2    C:\Development\Cordova\Golf\Code\IonicSideMenuStarter\MDAVSCLI  1   1   IonicSideMenuStarter
```

I also have a warning:

```
Warning 1   Acquiring Cordova Tools. Any build cancellation requests will be processed after acquisition has completed. IonicSideMenuStarter
```

I had, just before opening the project, downloaded and installed Cordova Tools for VS 2013 CTP 3.2. My IDE is VS 2013 Update 5, running on Win 10 upgraded from Win 7 just days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have installed all the requirements [found here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757054.aspx).

Secondly, ensure that everything is configured correctly as [described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771551.aspx), pay special attention to the Android SDK setup.

Lastly, you will need to update your [system variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn771551%20(v=vs.140).aspx#env_var).

Follow those steps and you should be golden.